# docker exec: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-16.04

every time I try to do:

```
$ docker exec
```

I get the error message:

```
 rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed:   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \"exit status 16\""
```

Session 1 (works like expected):

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
alpine              latest              baa5d63471ea        7 weeks ago         4.8 MB
hello-world         latest              c54a2cc56cbb        5 months ago        1.85 kB

$ docker run --rm --name alpine -it alpine sh
/ # pwd
/
```

Session 2:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7bd39b37aee2        alpine              "sh"                22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds                           alpine

$ docker exec -it alpine sh 
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \"exit status 16\""
$ docker exec -it 7bd39b37aee2 sh 
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \"exit status 16\""
```

/var/log/syslog shows some warnings, but I was neither able to understand the root cause not finding matching answers.

Thanks for any hint.

```
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
$ docker info

Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.13.0-rc3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 4
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 51371867a01c467f08af739783b8beafc154c4d7
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.487 GiB
Name: pb7tt6ts
ID: YQ4G:ETTP:5VCM:PAJD:F3KB:O7JN:AZOF:VLTI:SKH4:BTSR:KP7D:NXIZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

= = = 
/var/log/syslog  docker restart and steps above 
= = = 

Dec 13 14:28:09 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
Dec 13 14:28:09 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Dec 13 14:28:09 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Dec 13 14:28:09 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 13 14:28:09 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:09.291301057+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 1448"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25908.125394] audit: type=1400 audit(1481635690.357:28): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=1466 comm="apparmor_parser"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.370364923+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.387915069+01:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.388367650+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.388465142+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.388508739+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.389419384+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.397339748+01:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.628011070+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.743703578+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25908.510718] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1462]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.808510166+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.808575966+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=4d92237 graphdriver=aufs version=1.13.0-rc3
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:10.820562161+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts console-kit-daemon[3106]: console-kit-daemon[3106]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 226 was not found when attempting to remove it
Dec 13 14:28:10 pb7tt6ts console-kit-daemon[3106]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 226 was not found when attempting to remove it
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.206672] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1460]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.388393] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1460]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.492197] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[1460]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <warn>  [1481635696.7320] device (vethff6f844): failed to find device 35 'vethff6f844' with udev
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7340] manager: (vethff6f844): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/46)
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts systemd-udevd[1614]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethff6f844: No such file or directory
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <warn>  [1481635696.7345] device (veth13c2a1d): failed to find device 36 'veth13c2a1d' with udev
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts systemd-udevd[1615]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth13c2a1d: No such file or directory
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7417] manager: (veth13c2a1d): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/47)
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.509027] device veth13c2a1d entered promiscuous mode
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.509240] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth13c2a1d: link is not ready
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7632] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethff6f844, iface: vethff6f844)
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7632] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethff6f844, iface: vethff6f844): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7639] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth13c2a1d, iface: veth13c2a1d)
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635696.7640] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth13c2a1d, iface: veth13c2a1d): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:16.965015836+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:16.965090775+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Dec 13 14:28:16 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:16.965117179+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.808163] eth0: renamed from vethff6f844
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts acvpnagent[2339]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635697.0599] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethff6f844, iface: vethff6f844)
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts acvpnagent[2339]: A new network interface has been detected.
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635697.0600] device (vethff6f844): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts acvpnagent[2339]: Function: logInterfaces File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 2105 Invoked Function: logInterfaces Return Code: 0 (0x00000000) Description: IP Address Interface List: 192.168.178.24 172.17.0.1 9.145.68.34 FE80:0:0:0:D8B4:C1E0:F8E4:DB77 FE80:0:0:0:42:44FF:FEC9:5D85 FE80:0:0:0:60A9:A1FF:FEED:F31C
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635697.0604] device (veth13c2a1d): link connected
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481635697.0605] device (docker0): link connected
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.823988] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth13c2a1d: link becomes ready
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.824039] docker0: port 1(veth13c2a1d) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 14:28:17 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25914.824061] docker0: port 1(veth13c2a1d) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 14:28:18 pb7tt6ts acvpnagent[2339]: Function: tableCallbackHandler File: RouteMgr.cpp Line: 1723 Invoked Function: recv Return Code: 11 (0x0000000B) Description: unknown
Dec 13 14:28:18 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth13c2a1d.IPv6 with address fe80::60a9:a1ff:feed:f31c.
Dec 13 14:28:18 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: New relevant interface veth13c2a1d.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 13 14:28:18 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: Registering new address record for fe80::60a9:a1ff:feed:f31c on veth13c2a1d.*.
Dec 13 14:28:32 pb7tt6ts kernel: [25929.850840] docker0: port 1(veth13c2a1d) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 14:28:36 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:36.704565159+01:00" level=error msg="Error running exec in container: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \\\"exit status 16\\\"\"\n"
Dec 13 14:28:36 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:36.705362948+01:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/exec/8a78f29ef71d4c3ab982a8dd7a4a325e280766072dea7337860874a72c42f42c/resize returned error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: process not found for container"
Dec 13 14:28:46 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:46.921880770+01:00" level=error msg="Error running exec in container: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \\\"exit status 16\\\"\"\n"
Dec 13 14:28:46 pb7tt6ts dockerd[1436]: time="2016-12-13T14:28:46.922576933+01:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/exec/5ad25668cac553118b8c702f02c69b427436eb67d1488d4170641bcacfdad50b/resize returned error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: process not found for container"
```

As recommended I reverted to a *main* version of docker and installed docker-engine 1.12.4

```
$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.12.4
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 11
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.487 GiB
Name: pb7tt6ts
ID: YQ4G:ETTP:5VCM:PAJD:F3KB:O7JN:AZOF:VLTI:SKH4:BTSR:KP7D:NXIZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Furthermore, no success but different error:

```
$ docker exec -it alpine sh 
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \\\"exit status 17\\\"\"\n"
```

Corresponding /var/log/syslog from  service docker start (21:00), docker run ... (21:01), docker exec ... (21:01)

```
Dec 13 21:00:01 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Dec 13 21:00:01 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Dec 13 21:00:01 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Dec 13 21:00:01 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:01.468921183+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 8686"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49419.124965] audit: type=1400 audit(1481659202.536:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=8700 comm="apparmor_parser"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.550070413+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver \"aufs\""
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.572067603+01:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.572336166+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit."
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.572799562+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.579465999+01:00" level=info msg="Firewalld running: false"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.779165187+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.903085523+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.903179108+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.903208197+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=1564f02 graphdriver=aufs version=1.12.4
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:00:02.923282443+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Dec 13 21:00:02 pb7tt6ts systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49477.834789] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[8692]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49477.896566] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[8692]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.080340] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[8692]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.192100] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[8682]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <warn>  [1481659261.6125] device (veth2b5b07c): failed to find device 47 'veth2b5b07c' with udev
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts systemd-udevd[8810]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethc2e4873: No such file or directory
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.196917] device vethc2e4873 entered promiscuous mode
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6215] manager: (veth2b5b07c): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/63)
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <warn>  [1481659261.6222] device (vethc2e4873): failed to find device 48 'vethc2e4873' with udev
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6241] manager: (vethc2e4873): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/64)
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts systemd-udevd[8809]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for veth2b5b07c: No such file or directory
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.211913] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethc2e4873: link is not ready
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6454] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth2b5b07c, iface: veth2b5b07c)
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6454] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth2b5b07c, iface: veth2b5b07c): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6507] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc2e4873, iface: vethc2e4873)
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.6507] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/vethc2e4873, iface: vethc2e4873): no ifupdown configuration found.
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.557310] eth0: renamed from veth2b5b07c
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.9915] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth2b5b07c, iface: veth2b5b07c)
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.9916] device (veth2b5b07c): driver 'veth' does not support carrier detection.
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.9919] device (vethc2e4873): link connected
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts NetworkManager[1343]: <info>  [1481659261.9937] device (docker0): link connected
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.573434] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethc2e4873: link becomes ready
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.573503] docker0: port 1(vethc2e4873) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 21:01:01 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49478.573527] docker0: port 1(vethc2e4873) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 21:01:03 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vethc2e4873.IPv6 with address fe80::d02a:ecff:fea8:662c.
Dec 13 21:01:03 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: New relevant interface vethc2e4873.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 13 21:01:03 pb7tt6ts avahi-daemon[1217]: Registering new address record for fe80::d02a:ecff:fea8:662c on vethc2e4873.*.
Dec 13 21:01:17 pb7tt6ts kernel: [49493.628038] docker0: port 1(vethc2e4873) entered forwarding state
Dec 13 21:02:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:02:02.072027206+01:00" level=error msg="Error running exec in container: rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value \"oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \\\"process_linux.go:83: executing setns process caused \\\\\\\"exit status 17\\\\\\\"\\\"\\n\""
Dec 13 21:02:02 pb7tt6ts dockerd[8675]: time="2016-12-13T21:02:02.072759152+01:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.24/exec/00c0dcac7a178129a17cd9eb833d154d428f2a6efbcd0f421ab3c5c54e52a236/resize returned error: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: process not found for container"
```

Comment: May be it's related to docker server v. 1.13.0-rc3. Tried on docker server 1.12.3 (ubuntu 16.04) pulling alpine:latest and it works.

Comment: Using Docker 1.12.3 was exactly the same behavior. My hope was the most current version would fix it.

Comment: I have similar behaviour on a VM running Ubuntu 14.04 and docker 1.13.0 (upgraded today from 1.12.can't remember).  Both this version and the previous docker version had the same problem

Comment: After docker update to 1.13.1 the error is appears.
Looks it is a known error: \n
[link] https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/29794
Status: Open

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be closed on the StackOverflow, but it would be likely ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1):

From the linked issue is [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29794#issuecomment-323634214) which appears to be the root cause:

> I think I found the root reason. It's nothing to do with Docker.
>
> Actually docker exec always fail because of Symantec AutoProtect
>   running on my system. It loads a custom kernel module that add some
>   file operation hooks, which affects the result of setns.
>
> ```
> $ lsmod | grep symev
> symev_custom_dkms_x86_64 72166 2 symap_custom_dkms_x86_64
> ```
>
> The workaround is to disable Symantec AutoProtect and reboot.
>
> ```
> sudo update-rc.d autoprotect disable
> ```